# How to add scroll into Dhtmlx gantt chart and loads the data based on count

Tags: angular, gantt-chart

I am using DHTMLX GANTT chart. Here I am using scroll. My requirement is that first on load only 5 data will be showing,once we scroll remaining 5 data should load and same thing should continue. I am not able to put here all the code, I have added a demo for details code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skvn8x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fgantt.component.ts

### gantt.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
  ViewEncapsulation
} from "@angular/core";
import { TaskService } from "../services/task.service";
import { LinkService } from "../services/link.service";
import { Task } from "../models/task";
import { Link } from "../models/link";

import "dhtmlx-gantt";

@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  selector: "gantt",
  styleUrls: ["./gantt.component.css"],
  providers: [TaskService, LinkService],
  template: `
    <div #gantt_here class="gantt-chart"></div>
  `
})
export class GanttComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("gantt_here", { static: true }) ganttContainer: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private taskService: TaskService,
    private linkService: LinkService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    gantt.config.xml_date = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i";

    gantt.init(this.ganttContainer.nativeElement);
    gantt.attachEvent("onGanttScroll", function(left, top) {
      // any custom logic here
    });

    const dp = gantt.createDataProcessor({
      task: {
        update: (data: Task) => this.taskService.update(data),
        create: (data: Task) => this.taskService.insert(data),
        delete: id => this.taskService.remove(id)
      },
      link: {
        update: (data: Link) => this.linkService.update(data),
        create: (data: Link) => this.linkService.insert(data),
        delete: id => this.linkService.remove(id)
      }
    });

    var all_tasks = [];
    gantt.eachTask(function(task) {
      all_tasks.push(task.id);
    });

    gantt.attachEvent("onGanttScroll", function(left, top) {
      var last_visible_task = 0;

      gantt.eachTask(function(task) {
        if (gantt.getTaskRowNode(task.id)) last_visible_task = task.id;
      });
      if (last_visible_task == all_tasks[all_tasks.length - 1])
        gantt.message("Loading new tasks");
    });
    Promise.all([this.taskService.get(), this.linkService.get()]).then(
      ([data, links]) => {
        gantt.parse({ data, links });
      }
    );
  }
}
```

### gantt.component.css

```
@import "dhtmlx-gantt/codebase/dhtmlxgantt.css";

.gantt-chart {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DHTMLX Gantt doesn't have a built-in way to do that.
You need to use the Gantt API to implement a custom solution.
Here is an example of how it can be implemented:
http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/e0e09a8ae